# Overriding Joda DateTime toString in Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, jodatime, grails-plugin

So I'm using the JodaTime plugin in a grails project I'm implementing and I really don't like that it spits out the ISO8601 date format when I do a toString.  I've been constantly putting toString and passing in the default.date.format from the messages file, but that's cumbersome.   The majority of cases I just want it to do that automatically.  So naturally it makes sense to take advantage of Groovy's fabulous metaprogramming to override toString on the DateTime class.  But alas it doesn't work.  Hence this discussion:

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4210

So according to said discussion, if our class implements an interface to implement the toString method we need to override the interface's metaclass.   Looking at the joda code base, DateTime implements the ReadableDateTime interface which in turn inherits from ReadableInstant which is where the method signature is defined.  The actual implementation is done 4 classes up in the class hierarchy for DateTime (DateTime inherits from BaseDateTime inherits from AbstractDateTime inherits from AbstractInstant which implements toString without parameters).  With me so far?

So in theory this means I should override either the ReadableDateTime interface which doesn't actually have the toString signature or the ReadableInstant one which does.  The following code to override toString on ReadableDateTime does nothing.

```
ReadableDateTime.metaClass.toString = { ->
    delegate.toString(messageSource.getMessage(
        'default.date.format', null, LCH.getLocale()))
}
```

So then trying with ReadableInstant:

```
ReadableInstant.metaClass.toString = { ->
    delegate.toString(messageSource.getMessage(
        'default.date.format', null, LCH.getLocale()))
}
```

also does not have the desired result for the DateTime.toString method.  However, there are some interesting affects here.  Take a look at the following code:

```
def aiToString = AbstractInstant.metaClass.getMetaMethod("toString", [] as Class[])
def adtToString = AbstractDateTime.metaClass.getMetaMethod("toString", [] as Class[])
def bdtToString = BaseDateTime.metaClass.getMetaMethod("toString", [] as Class[])
def dtToString = DateTime.metaClass.getMetaMethod("toString", [] as Class[])

def date = new DateTime()
println "ai: ${aiToString.invoke(date)} "
println "adt: ${adtToString.invoke(date)} "
println "bdt: ${bdtToString.invoke(date)} "
println "dt: ${dtToString.invoke(date)} "
```

The first 3 methods show my date formatted just how I'd like it.  The last one is still showing the ISO8601 formatted date.  I thought maybe the JodaTime plugin for grails might be overriding the toString and they do add a few methods to these interfaces but nothing to do with toString.  At this point, I'm at a loss.  Anyone have ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You use DateTime as a field in another object? Or just return it to the view?

Comment: I basically use DateTime for any dates in my program.  So I have it on domain classes, forms, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cann't override `DateTime#toString()`, becouse `DateTime` class is `final`

```
public final class DateTime
```

But if you want another date format, you can use [toString(org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter)](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#toString%28org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter%29)
for example

```
def date = new DateTime();
date.toString(ISODateTimeFormat.basicDate()); // format yyyyMMdd
```

Comment: Is this really true?  I'm able to add a new method to the DateTime class I just can't seem to override the toString method?